# How to save div into a acf field?

Tags: php, wordpress

Hey I have a wordpress website with a bunch of tests, when you complete them an algorithm calculates results and then displays the answers,I would like to save the <`div class="result"> Answer </div>` to get copied to a acf field so I can display it later, how would I go about doing that? If there is some code needed please ask, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Create a textarea or a single input field with value as `<div class="result"> Answer </div>` and save. Then call using acf functions as using normally.